# Understanding PDO prepared statements to insert data in a database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm trying to understand PDO prepared statements. Did I implement them correctly in the code below?

```php
$guestFirstName = $_POST['guestFirstName'];
$guestLastName = $_POST['guestLastName'];
$guestMessage = $_POST['guestMessage'];

//remove whitespace from beginning and end
$guestName = trim($guestName);
$guestMessage = trim($guestMessage);

$errors = validate_inputs($guestFirstName, $guestLastName, $guestMessage);
//if there are no errors received.
    if (empty($errors)) {
      try {
        //open the database
        $db = new PDO(DB_PATH, DB_LOGIN, DB_PW);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        //insert the first name, last name, and message into the database
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO guest_users(first, last) VALUES(:f,:l);");
        $stmt->bindParam('f', $guestFirstName);
        $stmt->bindParam('l', $guestLastName);
        $stmt->execute();

        $insertID = $db->lastInsertId();
      
       $stmt2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO guest_message (comment, user_id, date_sent) VALUES (:m,:i, now());");
       $stmt2->bindParam('m', $guestMessage);
       $stmt2->bindParam('i', $insertID);
       $stmt2->execute();

        $displayName = $db->query("SELECT * FROM guest_users where id = '$insertID'")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $displayMessage = $db->query("SELECT * FROM guest_message where id = '$insertID'")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Below this is just HTML code where I'm inserting variables like `$displayName['first']`, `$displayMessage['message']`, etc. To display information from the database.

Comment: What is the question again?

Comment: did I implement prepared statements correctly. Is there a better way to implement them? Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Well you understood prepared prepared queries wrong. You have to prepare all queries, not just insert

Comment: I figured as much. How would i go about preparing queries? I don't really understand that.

Comment: You just did that in your question.

Comment: Just make your *select* queries prepared as well

Comment: You don't fetch before execute. See actual [examples](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples)

Comment: `$displayName = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM guest_users where id = :i");`

`$displayname->bindparam('i', $insertID);`


`$displayName->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

`$displayName->execute();`

Comment: Okay, so execute then fetch. thank you.

Comment: things like `$displayName['first']` no longer work. changing everything to `$query1` and, then `$displayName = $query1` doesn't work either.

Comment: Yes of course. See actual examples I gave you

Comment: Thanks. Guess my code was flawed so I rewrote it. Appreciate the help.